# How do I open the /var/www/html directory when using Visual Studio Code downloaded via Flatpak?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora, flatpak

After setting up my Apache server on Fedora, I discovered that I could not access the `/var/www` directory from Visual Studio Code. While I could navigate to the folder without any problem via the **files** gui and terminal, I could not access `/var/www` through VS Code.

Changing the permissions did not help, nor did launching VS Code directly from `/var/www` in the command line work either.

Comment: FYI, I've had good luck installing/updating `vscode` from the microsoft repo described at [Running VS Code on Linux](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup/linux/).

Comment: @rickhg12hs I installed directly from the microsoft repo. Works much better than flatpak. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After downloading VS Code from Flatpak for Fedora, I was not able to access my `/var/www/html` folder through VS Code.

#### Unsuccessful solutions:

- Using the terminal to open VS code directly from the folder with `flatpak run com.visualstudio.code`.
- Changing permissions to the /var/www folder.

#### Successful solution:

> Use terminal to open VS Code with `flatpak --filesystem=/var/www/html run com.visualstudio.code`. Then navigate to the `/var/www` folder in VS Code.

Note: this solution was answered [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-cannot-open-var-www-folder/57176/9), replacing atom for vscode.